# d3.js changing axes between linear to log-log with data array

Tags: d3.js

How would I go about to change the data format of the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6by4mq3s/

To be a 2D array with X and Y values instead of a one-dimensional array.

Basically changing this:

```
var data = [
                {
                name: "A",
                points: [10, 100, 1000]
                },
                {
                name: "B",
                points: [20, 200, 2000]
                }
                ];
```

To this:

```
var data = [
                {
                name: "A",
                points: [[10, 50], [100, 80], [1000, 200]]
                },
                {
                name: "B",
                points: [[20, 30], [200, 10], [2000, 5]]
                }
                ];
```

Currently, I get problems with not a function by simply trying to using:

```
.attr("cx", function (d,i) { return this.xScale(d[0]); } )
.attr("cy", function (d) { return this.yScale(d[1]); } )
```

Which I guess is due to scoping.

Comment: what is the logic for the `50 80 200` values?

Comment: no logic just some data for values on y.